# Loop through selected rows C# DevExpress

Tags: c#, count, devexpress, selected

I have a function that sets column values for all rows:

[image]

The code that sets this:

```
//Update the engineers for all rows 
Btn_ValidateClick_ItemClick(object sender,ItemClickEventArgs e)
{
    UpdateTotalTime(gridView);
}


private void UpdateEngineers(DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Base.ColumnView View)
{
    //Column name that need to be updated (set) 
    DevExpress.XtraGrid.Columns.GridColumn col = View.Columns.ColumnByFieldName("Engineers");
            try
            {
                int dataRowCount = View.DataRowCount; 
                for (int i = 0; i < dataRowCount; i++)
                {
                    GridView detail = (GridView)gridView.GetDetailView(i, 0);

                    string language = gridView.GetRowCellValue(i, "Language").ToString();

                    for (int y = 0; y < gridView.GetDetailView(i, 0).RowCount; y++)
                    {
                        //Add all values found in a detail column to an arraylist 
                        values.Add(detail.GetRowCellValue(y, "EngineerInitials").ToString());
                    }

                    if (values.Count >0 )
                           object t = //string join ...

                            View.SetRowCellValue(i, col, t);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            object t = "No engineers"

                            View.SetRowCellValue(i, col, t);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
}
```

The problem is that now, I want it only to set it for the rows that are selected.

I tried using the `.GetSelectedRows()`-function and adding the rows to an `ArrayList`, but this doesn't allow customability really:

```
private void UpdateTotalTime(DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Base.ColumnView View)
{
    ArrayList selectedRows = new ArrayList();
    for (int i = 0; i < gridView.SelectedRowsCount; i++)
    {
        if (gridView.GetSelectedRows()[i] >= 0)
        selectedRows.Add(gridView.GetDataRow(gridView.GetSelectedRows()[i]));
    }
            try
            {

                int count = View.GetSelectedRows().Count();
                for (int i = 0; i < selectedRows.Count; i++)
                {
                    //This gets the first row of the count, not the first selected row
                    GridView detail = (GridView)gridView.GetDetailView(i,0);
                }
            }
```

If I select the 3 bottom rows, the first 3 get updated. Why is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are adding all the selected rows to your `selectedRows` `ArrayList`. But after that, you are not using it for anything. 
I guess what you want (I've never used `devexpress` controls) is using those selectedrows `RowHandle` to pass it to the `GetDetailView` method. According to the [`GetSelectedRows`](https://documentation.devexpress.com/windowsforms/DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Base.ColumnView.GetSelectedRows.method) documentation, the method returns the int handles of the selected rows, so your code should look like this:

First, you must save the `DataRow` handles, not the `DataRow` itself, so you must change in your code this line:

```
selectedRows.Add(gridView.GetDataRow(gridView.GetSelectedRow‌​s()[i]));
```

into this:

```
selectedRows.Add(gridView.GetSelectedRows()[i]);
```

And then, change your loop into this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < selectedRows.Count; i++)
{
   int rowHandle = (int)selectedRows[i];
   GridView detail = (GridView)gridView.GetDetailView(rowHandle,0);
}
```

In fact, you could do everything in just one loop:

```
private void UpdateTotalTime(DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Base.ColumnView View)
{
     for (int i = 0; i < gridView.SelectedRowsCount; i++)
     {
          int rowHandle = gridView.GetSelectedRows()[i];
          GridView detail = (GridView)gridView.GetDetailView(rowHandle,0);
     } 
}
```

Comment: that's exactly what I need to do (pass the `rowhandle` of the row to the GetDetailView). But I can not get the rowhandle of the row using what you suggested sadly :/

Comment: Row is not an integer (can't parse it neither). Row also doesn't contain methods or parameters like `.getRowHandle` or `RowHandle` or `IndexAt`,...

Comment: According to [this](https://documentation.devexpress.com/windowsforms/DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Base.ColumnView.GetSelectedRows.method),`GetSelectedRows` returns the selected rows handle, so there you have your int. Try the second code i posted and see if it works

Comment: Thanks but it gives me the error  `The as operator must be used with a reference type or nullable type ('int' is a non-nullable value type) `

Comment: Yes, that was my mistake. Try using `int rowHandle = (int)selectedRows[i];` instead

Comment: That gives me the error `Specified cast is not valid` :/ I'm thinking that this is not possible

Comment: Oh,now i see the problem. You are adding the datarow instead of the rowhandle. Change now this `selectedRows.Add(gridView.GetDataRow(gridView.GetSelectedRows()[i]));` into this: `selectedRows.Add(gridView.GetSelectedRows()[i]);`

Comment: Thank you so much!!!!!!!!!!! I was nearly pulling my hair out from the frustration. thanks!